# ng-bootstrap -- no regular button component?

Tags: ng-bootstrap

I'm using ng-bootstrap in an Angular project and I see checkbox and radio components in the components list (NgbCheckBox, NgbRadioGroup) but no regular button.

Am I crazy or is there no regular button component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "regular button component" as we (authors of [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/)) didn't feel like there is a need to a particular directive / component for buttons as in our view such a component / directive wouldn't provide any added value.

We are very careful about not coding / shipping components or directives that would introduce new abstractions without providing enough value. A component or directive needs to do something "useful" to make it into ng-bootstrap codebase. In general we see those things as providing value and thus justifying new abstraction:

- JS behaviour (ex. positioning tooltips, toggling collapse with animations, opening modal etc.);
- encapsulating markup that is repetitive / verbose to write by hand;
- enhancing markup with accessibility support (screen readers, keyboard navigation etc.) that would be tricky to do "by hand";

[WIKI article with more detailed reasoning](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/wiki/What-qualifies-as-a-ng-bootstrap-directive-or--component%3F).

If you believe that a directive / component for a button would be a worthwhile addition, feel free to open an issue to discuss.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you!